# How to Properly Stop Electronic Speed Controller

Tags: gpio, pwm, electronics, dc-motor

I have a brushless electronic speed controller connected to my RaspberryPi. I have tuned it to 700 - 2000. It runs correctly, but whenever I set the speed to 700, it stops (this is supposed to happen) and then starts beeping (2 second intervals, meaning irregular throttle signal). Is the beeping supposed to happen?

This is the code I am running:

```py
import pigpio
import time

pin = 4

pi = pigpio.pi()

print("Step 1")

pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pin, 0)

time.sleep(1)

print("Step 2")

pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pin, 700)

time.sleep(1)

print("Step 3")

for x in range(2000, 700, -100):
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pin, x)
        time.sleep(1)

print("Off")

pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pin, 700)

input("")
```

Comment: your question is not about Raspberry Pi ... it is off topic here

Comment: You will need to find the documentation for the ESC you are using.  It may say what the beeps mean.

Comment: @joan The beeping means 'throttle signal is irregular'